# Flipping an Image in C Code

Tags: c

I need to be able to flip an image horizontally in c by manipulating the pixels in the png file. Despite my attempts, when tested, my algorithm does nothing. I also need to be able to do this vertically but here is my code for the horizontal flip:

```
void flip_horizontal( uint8_t array[], unsigned int cols, unsigned int rows ) {
    unsigned int left = 0;
    unsigned int right = cols;

    for(int r = 0; r < rows; r++){  
        while(left != right && right > left){
            int temp = array[r * cols + left];
            array[(r * cols) + left] = array[(r * cols) + cols - right];
            array[(r * cols) + cols - right] = temp;
            right--;
            left++;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You need do decode it first, not an easy task. It is not .bmp.

Comment: you need to reset right left after processing each row?

Comment: you can use SDL (libsdl.org) to decode the image to a surface and that should give you pretty straight forward access to the pixels/color channels.  From there you can find a few libraries (or even use SDL_SaveBMP() to save the surface to a file.

Comment: how comes it's just an array of `uint8_t`?

Comment: @HuStmpHrrr each channel of color is 8 bits.

Comment: @MikeMcMahon sure, but it's colorful, right?

Comment: Like @γηράσκωδ'αείπολλάδιδασκόμε said, you need to decode the PNG file first. I find [libgd](http://libgd.bitbucket.org/) very easy to work with. Also, your code is flawed anyway. You will need to reset the values of `left` and `right` for each value of `r`, and you probably want to initialize `right` to `cols-1` if your data is indexed from zero.

Comment: the data type is not important to the situation, you can ignore that. Assume the file does not need to be decoded. In the current context of my problem, it does not need to be decoded. (I also believe the png im working from is decoded already)

Comment: hmm @squeamishossifrage's suggestions almost worked, i drew a handsome lien right down the middle of the image and nothing was swapped

Comment: Oh, right. That's because `r*cols+left` and `r*cols+cols-right` are the same thing. Replace the inner loop with `for(i=cols/2;i;i--){t=array[r*cols+i];array[r*cols+i]=array[r*(cols+1)+i-1];array[r*(cols+1)+i-1]=t;}`

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to reset `left` and `right` after processing the first row.

```
void flip_horizontal( uint8_t array[], unsigned int cols, unsigned int rows ) {
    unsigned int left = 0;
    unsigned int right = cols;

    for(int r = 0; r < rows; r++){  
        while(left != right && right > left){
            int temp = array[r * cols + left];
            array[(r * cols) + left] = array[(r * cols) + cols - right];
            array[(r * cols) + cols - right] = temp;
            right--;
            left++;
        }

        // Reset left and right after processing a row.
        left = 0;
        right = cols;
    }
}
```

**Update**

You are computing the indices wrong. Take a look at the following line.

```
            array[(r * cols) + left] = array[(r * cols) + cols - right];
```

when `left = 0`, `right = cols`,

```
(r * cols) + left == (r * cols) + cols - right
```

when `left = n`, `right = cols - n`, and still

```
(r * cols) + left == (r * cols) + cols - right
```

That's why you don't see any change to the image.

Try:

```
void flip_horizontal( uint8_t array[], unsigned int cols, unsigned int rows ) {
    unsigned int left = 0;
    unsigned int right = cols-1;

    for(int r = 0; r < rows; r++){  
        while(left != right && right > left){
            int index1 = r * cols + left;
            int index2 = r * cols + right;

            int temp = array[index1];
            array[index1] = array[index2];
            array[index2] = temp;
            right--;
            left++;
        }

        // Reset left and right after processing a row.
        left = 0;
        right = cols-1;
    }
}
```

Comment: image still has not flipped despite me making these changes, ill keep them though

Comment: oh i see now. that is also implemented much better, cleaner. how would I do the same thing if i wanted to flip it from top to bottom?